# wmic product get does not get all programs

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

When I use

```
wmic product get name name,version
```

I get a list where are showed all programs installed on my PC, but still there are not all programs listed. When I go to control panel >  Uninstall programs I see more programs

Comment: Any specific examples of programs that are missing? Are they "standard" applications or ones installed from the Windows Store?

Comment: @Mokubai Extensions for autodesk maya that are showed in control panel > Uninstall programs, VLC player. Also I when I use 'wmic product get name name,version' in cmd and when I use in powershell 'Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize' there could be some differences

Comment: You can edit the details into your question. There should be and "improve" or "edit" link just below the question body.

Comment: If you run: `wmic product list > 1.txt` you will see that they are all MSI based.  I assume you are missing anything that isn't MSI based.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What exactly is your question?  As your question is currently written, I can't tell if an answer actually answers your question or not, you should consider modifying to make it clear what your question is exactly.  The command you used, only returns registered programs, not all programs when they are installed created the required registry key.

Answer (score 11):

> Per Microsoft: [The Win32_Product WMI class represents products as they are installed by Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx) (AKA .MSI installer files, msiexec)

[Since there are other installers/software-packagers (InstallShield, Wise, NSIS [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System])](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software#Windows) that apparently don't register themselves in WMI (since they may predate it) I guess we have to query in multiple locations :(. Standards are changing, as IT always is so this is just the reality we have to deal with. As you've [already mentioned in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1308957/wmic-product-get-does-not-get-all-programs#comment1945724_1308957) you can query the registry in these locations for all the other apps:
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` &
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

I guess WMI queries registry at this location: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products`

Here are some links with additional info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673233/wmi-installed-query-different-from-add-remove-programs-list
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/