# I am trying to make a WMIC batch file to get me a list of installed software

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Disclaimer: i am not an expert at this.  I put this script together based on combining multiple samples i saw from other scripts.

My goal is to use WMIC to output a CSV file of the current logged in user and all the software based on a list of PCs (PCLIST.txt)  Here is what i have so far:

```
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (PCLIST.txt) do if exist "\\%%a\c$" (
WMIC /NODE: "%%a" COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME /format:csv >> ENVINV.csv
wmic /NODE: "%%a" Product get name, vendor /format:csv >> ENVINV.csv

  ) ELSE (
  @ECHO %%a does not exist.  Writing to text file.
  @ECHO %%a >>ENVINV-error.txt
  )

)
```

This is what i get as output:

> Node,UserName
> CCOMPUTER1,CCHNL\username
> Node,Name,Vendor
> CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft OneNote MUI (English) 2016,Microsoft Corporation
> CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft Office OSM MUI (English) 2016,Microsoft
> Corporation CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft Office Standard 2016,Microsoft
> Corporation CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft Office OSM UX MUI (English)
> 2016,Microsoft Corporation CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft Office Shared Setup
> Metadata MUI (English) 2016,Microsoft Corporation CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft
> Excel MUI (English) 2016,Microsoft Corporation CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft
> Office Shared 64-bit Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2016,Microsoft
> Corporation CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft PowerPoint MUI (English)
> 2016,Microsoft Corporation CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft Publisher MUI
> (English) 2016,Microsoft Corporation CCOMPUTER1,Microsoft Outlook MUI
> (English) 2016,Microsoft Corporation

---

While workable, it would be much easier to sort and view if:

1. there was no blank line at the top
2. the First Line was simply just, "Node, Name, Vendor"
3. the "Node" lines did not repeat for each time it cycled the for Loop

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be a batch file PowerShell would be far better for this. Also I would strongly discourage wmic product which just wraps win32_product class.  This will reconfigure all MSI products (check the App event log) on the computer (which is why it takes so long) and it only lists MSI based products.

Comment: Maybe see my post here https://superuser.com/questions/1603763/how-can-i-run-a-single-command-to-show-all-installed-applications-in-windows-10/1603935#1603935

Comment: I was trying to do this with PowerShell, but it also required me to enable some things in the computers as well, plus i couldn't get it as close to what i wanted so far as this.  I've got it so close, i'm reluctant to start over with PowerShell.  I'll take a look at the thread you mentioned.  Thanks!

Comment: Performance aside, you will miss a third of software I would think. Windows Installer is probably being used less rather than more these days.

Comment: Thank you.  Right now it's just a minor thing that i can work around.  Otherwise it gives me the info i need.  Luckily i don't need a list of everything.  The specific things i'm looking for all use the windows installer show they show up here.

Comment: @zwin You can get inspired from this [answer too with Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1603763/how-can-i-run-a-single-command-to-show-all-installed-applications-in-windows-10/1626411#1626411)